# send a forgotten password mail in iphone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, password-protection, forgot-password

I am making an login form. On that form I have a *forgotten password* button. What I want to do know is that an e-mail is send to the user using it's email adress.

Anybody has an idea how to do this in an iphone app?

Kind regards.

Comment: You don't send the email from the device, you do this from the server.

Comment: you can't get the users email adress automaticly, if that's your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, your server (the one you are logging on to) will send that mail, not the iPhone app. When you press that button, you notify the server to send your user an email.